# Oracle SQL query using group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I've two tables

```
CREATE TABLE DBTEST.EMP
(
  EMP_ID   NUMBER,
  NAME     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  SALARY   NUMBER,
  DEPT_ID  NUMBER,
  LOC_ID   NUMBER
)

CREATE TABLE DBTEST.LOC
(
  LOC_ID       NUMBER,
  CODE         VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
)
```

sample data

```
EMP_ID  NAME        SALARY  DEPT_ID LOC_ID
1       Timmins     180000  1       1
2       Lauchnor    180000  1       1
4       Anderson            4       1
11      Pitcher     116000  3       2
17      Hedrick     182000  3       2
25      Mandurino   182000  2       1
69      Frenzel     62000   4       3



LOC_ID  CODE    DESCRIPTION
1       UT      Utah
2       CA      California
3       EU      Europe
```

I want to list employees with below-average salaries for their location? 
Note: this is a group by example.

I hope you understand it.

Thanks

Comment: haha, no. I was looking at a few samples of group by clause and came up with this. The query that was written by the author of the article is wrong and I could not figure out how to fix it

Comment: This is what author wrote which is totally wrong

SELECT E.NAME 
FROM EMP E
WHERE E.SALARY < ( SELECT MAX(AVG(SALARY))
FROM EMP E1,LOC L
WHERE E1.LOC_ID = L.LOC_ID
GROUP BY L.LOC_ID)
GROUP BY E.LOC_ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
Select emp.*
  From DBTEST.EMP emp,
    (Select Avg(Salary) avg_salary, loc_id From DBTEST.EMP Group By LOC_ID) averages
  Where averages.loc_id = emp.loc_id
    And emp.salary < averages.avg_salary;
```

This meets your requirement of using a `Group By`, but if given the choice, I would have done without, like this:

```
Select *
  From DBTEST.EMP emp
  Where salary <
    (Select Avg(salary) From DBTEST.EMP emp2 Where emp2.loc_id = emp.loc_id);
```

This has been tested, and both queries return the following:

```
"EMP_ID","NAME","SALARY","DEPT_ID","LOC_ID"
"2","Lauchnor","180000","1","1"
"1","Timmins","180000","1","1"
"11","Pitcher","116000","3","2"
```

Comment: Not totally true but probably gives me the idea of how to deal with it.Thanks

Comment: Your query gives this result. I hope you understand

-------First Record ----------
2 Lauchnor 180000 1 1 180666.666666667 1
-------Second Record ----------
1 Timmins 180000 1 1 180666.666666667 1
-------Third Record ----------
11 Pitcher 116000 3 2 149000 2

Comment: @Ali - what do you think is wrong with these results?  Each of these 3 employees is below the salary average for their expected location.

Comment: @Ali - I'm way ahead of you - was already editing my answer to include an example without the Group By.  No employee of location #3 is shown, as it's difficult to be below average when you're the only one being compared against.  (Frenzel is all alone in Europe.)

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use `AVG()` as a window function (analytic function in Oracle lingo) in this situation:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT emp_id, name, salary
         , dept_id, loc_id
         , AVG(salary) OVER ( PARTITION BY loc_id ) AS avg_salary
      FROM emp
) WHERE salary < avg_salary;
```

[Please refer to SQL Fiddle demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c311/2)